# Python: Routes to files don't find with testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm newbie testing python and I have a testing class with several testing methods. If I run all testing methods the route to a file it doesn't find but If I comment all methods except one of them then the test works fine and the file searched before is found it.

This code works fine. You can see that all methods are commented except constructor and one testing method

```
import unittest
from constants import COMPETITIONS, SEASON
from process.team_update_advanced_stats import TeamUpdateAdvancedStats
import os
import decimal as dec


class TestTeamUpdateAdvancedStats(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, test):
        super().__init__(test)
        os.chdir("../")

    # def test_get_list_teams(self):
    #     data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams[0]["id"], 769, "Error: El ID de equipo no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams[4]["id_team_feb"], 816649, "Error el ID FEB de equipo no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams[7]["name"], "RPK ARASKI", "Error nombre del equipo no es el correcto")

    # def test_get_teams_std_stats(self):
    #     data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
    #     self.assertEqual(len(data.teams_std_stats), 14, "Error: El número de filas devueltas no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[1][770]["t2p_conv"], 583, "Error: El número de T2PConv no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[5][774]["tc_percentage"], round(dec.Decimal(39.48), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[10][779]["ppa"], round(dec.Decimal(0.86), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[12][781]["total_puntos_pp"], round(dec.Decimal(70.87), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
    #     self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[13][782]["pointsbyposs"], round(dec.Decimal(0.79), 2), "Error: Los puntos por posesión no son correctos correcto")

    def test_get_opps_std_stats(self):
        data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
        self.assertEqual(len(data.opps_std_stats), 14, "Error: El número de filas devueltas no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[1][770]["t2p_conv"], 382, "Error: El número de T2PConv no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[5][774]["tc_percentage"], round(dec.Decimal(41.84), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[10][779]["ppa"], round(dec.Decimal(0.87), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[12][781]["total_puntos_pp"], round(dec.Decimal(60.74), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[13][782]["pointsbyposs"], round(dec.Decimal(0.96), 2), "Error: Los puntos por posesión no son correctos correcto")
```

But, If I uncomment all the code:

```
import unittest
from constants import COMPETITIONS, SEASON
from process.team_update_advanced_stats import TeamUpdateAdvancedStats
import os
import decimal as dec


class TestTeamUpdateAdvancedStats(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, test):
        super().__init__(test)
        os.chdir("../")

    def test_get_list_teams(self):
        data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
        self.assertEqual(data.teams[0]["id"], 769, "Error: El ID de equipo no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams[4]["id_team_feb"], 816649, "Error el ID FEB de equipo no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams[7]["name"], "RPK ARASKI", "Error nombre del equipo no es el correcto")

    def test_get_teams_std_stats(self):
        data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
        self.assertEqual(len(data.teams_std_stats), 14, "Error: El número de filas devueltas no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[1][770]["t2p_conv"], 583, "Error: El número de T2PConv no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[5][774]["tc_percentage"], round(dec.Decimal(39.48), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[10][779]["ppa"], round(dec.Decimal(0.86), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[12][781]["total_puntos_pp"], round(dec.Decimal(70.87), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.teams_std_stats[13][782]["pointsbyposs"], round(dec.Decimal(0.79), 2), "Error: Los puntos por posesión no son correctos correcto")

    def test_get_opps_std_stats(self):
        data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
        self.assertEqual(len(data.opps_std_stats), 14, "Error: El número de filas devueltas no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[1][770]["t2p_conv"], 382, "Error: El número de T2PConv no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[5][774]["tc_percentage"], round(dec.Decimal(41.84), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[10][779]["ppa"], round(dec.Decimal(0.87), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[12][781]["total_puntos_pp"], round(dec.Decimal(60.74), 2), "Error: El TC% no es el correcto")
        self.assertEqual(data.opps_std_stats[13][782]["pointsbyposs"], round(dec.Decimal(0.96), 2), "Error: Los puntos por posesión no son correctos correcto")
```

I've got this error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/test/test_team_update_advanced_stats.py", line 21, in test_get_teams_std_stats
    data = TeamUpdateAdvancedStats(COMPETITIONS.LF1, SEASON.LF1)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/process/team_update_advanced_stats.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.teams = self.get_list_teams(competition, id_season)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/process/team_update_advanced_stats.py", line 34, in get_list_teams
    return TeamUpdateAdvancedStats.get_data(competition, args, "teams.by.season=")
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/process/team_update_advanced_stats.py", line 22, in get_data
    data = SearchData(args, query)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/ddbb/feb/data/search.py", line 18, in __init__
    q = query.getQuery(query_name)
  File "/home/josecarlos/Workspace/python/basketmetrics/com/files/queryreader.py", line 12, in getQuery
    with open(self.getURL()) as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './files/querys.sql'
```

How is that possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You `chdir` to the parent directory before each test, but don't change back. You can either change back in `tearDown()`, or use some other, less fragile means to define the directory (for example by using `__file__` as base).

Comment: Thank you @MrBeanBremen for your appreciated help!!!